# Timer Interrupt in Linux C

Tags: c, linux, timer, signals, interrupt

Am working on a LTE host testing application where I have call a function A at first ofdma symbol and another function B on 7th OFDMA symbol where a frame will have 14 ofdma symbols. Let me take care care of the timing later. But how to implement this C with Linux.

Is there any sample code that explains on timer and software interrupts. I have 2 separate binaries running where once will give me the time. Let say a frame tick is 1 second. This one second will be divided into 14 and function A and B will be called 1st and 7st part of a second.

Considering linux interrupt or timer or signals, Suggest me which will be efficient in this case. Any info on how to implement this.

Comment: What does *"pseudo code that explains on timer and software interrupts"* mean?

Comment: Not Pseudo may be a sample code might help

Answer (score 0):

IMO the timer callback (which can be considered as timer interrupt :) ) can be only done if you start a new thread, which will call your callback functions when the time condition(s) is (are) met.